# How to convert rogue query into Mysql ?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, scala

i found a code that written in `Rogue` that is

`Rogue is a type-safe internal Scala DSL for constructing and executing find and modify commands against MongoDB in the Lift web framework`

i found code that is written in `scala` that is query to fetch data

and i want to convert that code into `mysql` query

```
def getBlogScore(word: String, blog: String): Long = Keyword.where(_.word eqs word).and(_.blog eqs blog)
    .fetch.map(_.score._1)
    .reduceLeftOption(_ + _).getOrElse(0)
```

give me some idea!

Comment: What does the schema for your MySQL database look like?

Comment: Schema is simple where `table` name is `keyword` and `word` ,`blog`,`score` is column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.reduceLeft( _ + _ )` would add all the scores together, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
SELECT SUM(score)
FROM keyword
WHERE blog = 'blog'
AND word = 'word'
```